# Github Search API - exclude repositories with language:null

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to get repositories from Github that use a language. Any repository with language:null must me excluded.
Is there a way to do this ?

Here's why've tried but not working

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=500+-language:null&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=100
```

Comment: I don't think `-` (to invert a search term) or `null` as a language value are supported by the API. I think client-side filtering of the results here is a necessary workaround.